# What does the phrase to have one's clock wiped mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Example: "That war has raged, since 1987, 20 years after the Satan got its clocked wiped"

It's a quote from a facebook post. What was intended is most probably "got its clock wiped" and it is merely a typo. Does such a phrase exist? What is its meaning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a modified version of the idiomatic expression ***[to clean someone's clock](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/clean_someone%27s_clock),*** (to defeat decisively):

> - In American English, ***[to clean someone's clock](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-cle1.htm)*** means to trounce one’s opponents in a game (“We’ll clean the Dodgers’ clocks today”) or generally to inflict a severe reverse (“Republicans got their clocks cleaned in November’s elections”),  (World Wide Words).

Comment: Please link your [source](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-cle1.htm) for quotation;  perhaps also [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clean_someone's_clock). (Oddly, Urban Dictionary favors a rather different sense.)

Comment: Yeah, it's a fairly rare expression anymore.  In fact, I don't recall hearing it in 30-40 years.  (Never did figure out what the metaphor is.)

Comment: Thanks Josh! The phrase I quoted was used by none other than the Moshiach (the Jewish Messiah prophesied to ascend the throne of David and become the King of Israel ushering redemption). What he meant was the defeat of Pan-Arabist plans to destroy Israel in the Six Day War in 1967. What now is unfolding is the Gog vs Magog, the mother of all wars. Follow him on FB and Twitter: https://www.facebook.com/yehoshua.yaacov, https://twitter.com/yyba1Israel